# VSIX Project Templates targeting Visual Studio 2010 and 2012

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, visual-studio-templates

I am creating a few Visual Studio Project Templates, and wrapping them in a VSIX for eventual upload to the Visual Studio Gallery. I would like one single VSIX to support installing the templates on both Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012.

What I would like to do is target some of my Project Templates (.vstemplate) so that they only install on a particular version of Visual Studio. For example, if I have VS2010.vstemplate and VS2012.vstemplate, when I run the VSIX on VS 2012, I don't want the VS2010 project template to  install and be available in the list of templates.

Is this possible with a single VSIX?

Comment: I am also attempting one. Let me know if you have found any procedures or guidance

Comment: did you get any result? I need to deploy new template for vs2012 and up .

Answer (score 0):

It seems kind of strange that you'd need different templates for the different versions of Visual Studio, but you could create an [`IWizard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.templatewizard.iwizard.aspx) implementation and a single [multi-project template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that includes both templates but doesn't define any [`ProjectTemplateLink Element`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171398.aspx). When the wizard runs you can detect the version of VS and use the [`AddFromTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte._solution.addfromtemplate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to create a project for the correct VSTemplate.